# No validation don't show next fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation, fieldset

I'm creating a multi-step form using this example - `codepen.io/orozcokapo/pen/LmgjYg`

But, I want that in second fieldset, first validate required input textfield (I am using only one Textfield on second fieldset for mobile number input) and the button to go to the next step should work if the required field is not empty.

I am unable to code it in JQuery. Could you please guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, designate which inputs are required by giving them the `required` attribute. Then, at the Next button's click function, move `current_fs = $(this).parent();` to the top and add this code

```
var inputs = current_fs.find("input[required]");
if(inputs.is((i,el) => $(el).val() == ""))
{
    alert("Please fill out all required fields");
    return false;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zaeNMP

Comment: Thanks for help. This code is not working. Throwing error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`

Comment: Did you add the block of code immediately after the `current_fs` line?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Thanks working now. But, when onclick submit if required field is empty it is displaying alert and if I enter value to input field on same page without refreshing then submit button is not clicakble. How to solve this now?

Comment: That sounds like it merits a separate question

Comment: Okay Thanks for help. I will try to solve this problem. If not, then will post a question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DoomTay its working now. I just changed this form tag - `<form id="msform" onSubmit="return false;">`